# Best way of learning to make iOS apps?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I wanted to know what would be the steps required to build an app like 'SnapChat' etc.? What platform or framework could this be built on and what languages tools etc would be used to create an app that using similar functions to snapChat or any similar app?

Any good learning resources would be really appreciated!

Comment: Please don't treat SO like Google. Its your own research that would make sense.

Comment: @john5, did you really expect us to write you a complete development plan for this. You are asking us for Platform, Framework suggestions, steps to get started on an app that not everyone knows about. Stack Overflow was meant as a way for developers helping developers, not developers writing code for lazy developers. You need to have a basic understanding of the concept being asked and ask a very specific question. This is like asking: How do I build a house... like the 5 bedroom house at XXXX address... whats a good material to use, how do draw the designs.

Comment: @John5 - "That, for me, is what SO is for." - not quite. `Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, to create and develop an iOS or Mac app you need a Mac and Apple's developing environment called Xcode (free on the Mac App Store).
In order to upload your App to the App Store and make it available to the public you need to have a valid iOS Developers Program license available here for 99$/year: [iOS Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/)
Next you need to learn Objective-C, which is the programming language used to write iOS/Mac Apps. Try to search for tutorials on the web or read books. That's basically how I dived in to this new world. Later on I literally learned by doing.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at classes at treehouse http://teamtreehouse.com/library/topic:ios.

You will need to sign up for an Apple Developer Account, download Xcode, learn Objective-C, learn Core Foundation, and learn UIKit to get started.